# Why can't I change my Broadcom 802.11n wireless card properties?

Tags: mac-address

I'm using Windows 7.

- Ethernet nic : Atheros AR8152 Fast Ethernet
- Wireless nic : Broadcom 802.11n

Follwing this : http://www.howtogeek.com/192173/how-and-why-to-change-your-mac-address-on-windows-linux-and-mac/

I'm trying to spoof my wireless MAC address for educationnal purpose.

When I go to the Ethernet (Atheros) card, I can see "Network Address" in the properties.

But for my wireless card (Broadcom 802.11n), I can't see "Network Address".  I only see (as shown in the picture) "Locally Administrered MAC Address". When I change that value, it does not affect my MAC address i.e `getmac` still shows the original MAC address.

[image]

Any idea how I could actually change (i.e. SPOOF) my wireless MAC address ?

Comment: Properties like this are handled by the driver. Verify the device driver being used is the optimal one.  Which properties will be listed might differ from manufacture to manufacture.  So "Network Address" might not be a property of Broadcom network adapators. Atheros and Broadcom are different cards.

Comment: @Ramhound So is there a way to know which property I should use for spoofing MAC here ? (if at all possible)

Comment: May not even be possible.  Not all adapters are made equally (even if it is an option for Broadcom, it may not be an option given by the device manufacturer).